# How to get vuejs static asset urls to resolve in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my css file  I have the line: `background-image: url(/img/bg.svg);`

In dev mode this resolves to `src/img/bg.svg` (the stylesheet is at `src/css/components/styles.css`)

But in prod mode, I see a 404 error in console that `bg.svg` was not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a path relative to the CSS file, rather than absolute, because [relative paths are resolved through Webpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) while absolute paths are preserved as-is, so they work mostly by luck.

Another way is to put the image in the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder), but it puts more responsibility onto you to make sure that the paths is correct, that your web server is configured correctly, and so on.

Comment: I've tried that but can't get it to work in dev. E.g if I do: `background-image: url(../../img/bg.svg);` (css is at `src/css/components/styles.css`) I get the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../img/bg.svg' in '/home/ali/dev/ali/<snip>/src/css`

Comment: I'd prefer not to use `public` because ideally I'd like it if the svg could be inlined within the prod code, if that's possible. If it'll always result in an extra http req then public is fine I guess

Comment: Is your CSS processed by Webpack also? How are you including it?

Comment: Yeah that might be it, I'm including `<style lang="scss" src="@/css/app.scss" />` in the main component, that  sass file includes others including `styles.scss`

Comment: May be that's why its not being processed by webpack?

Comment: Yep, that looks to be it. Thanks!